# Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial exercise no. 1 hints

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I know I'm asking for a lot in this post but after reading 4 books on Ruby/Rails I'm frustrated by the fact that I'm not getting the "aha" moment.  If someone can help I'll come over and cook you breakfast (for a week).

I'm coming from the world of PHP/MySQL and I'm finding it difficult to grasp certain things in Rails.  The last book I read by Michael Hartl suggests some exercises to add to the application he's built in the book.  It has to do with associations.  So I was wondering if someone could give me some hints how to go about this because I'm really stuck.

The application he builds is almost a Twitter clone.  There are Users who post Microposts.  Their home page looks like this http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#fig:home_page_with_feed  The User's own Microposts are posted along the right hand side in the 'feed'.  Along with the User's Microposts in the feed are also Microposts by Users that are being followed by the current User.  You can follow and unfollow any User you want.

The exercise suggests adding @replies.  A @reply is a Micropost starting with @username (e.g. '@mikeglaz how are you').  This Micropost will then appear in your feed and the username's feed (not necessarily someone you're following).  The author suggests the following: 'This might involve adding an in_reply_to column in the microposts table and an extra including_replies scope to the Micropost model.'  But the associations regarding following other users are pretty complex and this is what's keeping me stuck.  I'll post some code:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
       class_name:  "Relationship",
       dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end
end

end
```

**Relationship**

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

**Micropost**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = user.followed_user_ids
    where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", followed_user_ids, user)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, what's your concrete question? You simply don't have to look at the complicated User associations, that as a hint! (I found them confusing, too, with all the followed and and followed by. But the change mainly goes into the Micropost model, so you should start with that following the hints that Michael Hartl gives.

If you want to, you can peek at my solution which I added 14 days ago at

https://github.com/htw-rails/TutorialSampleApp32/

- some of the source code might look a bit different, as this version has grown out of the Tutorial for the Rails 3.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I am finding people by using username....and i specifically added the code that allows @reply to work. You should have already finished with the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl

**DATABASE**

```
class CreateRecipients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipients do |t|
      t.string :user_id
      t.string :micropost_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :recipients
  end
end
```

**MODELS**

```
class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :micropost_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost

end


class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :recipients
  belongs_to :user

  USERNAME_REGEX = /@\w+/i

  has_many :recipients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :replied_users, :through => :recipients, :source => "user"

  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  after_save :save_recipients

  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                     WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", 
          user_id: user.id)
  end

  private

    def self.followed_by(user)
      followed_ids = %(SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                    WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
      micropost_ids = %(SELECT micropost_id FROM recipients
                    WHERE user_id = :user_id)
      where("id IN (#{micropost_ids}) OR user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id",
      {:user_id => user})
    end

    def save_recipients
      return unless reply?

      people_replied.each do |user|
        Recipient.create!(:micropost_id => self.id, :user_id => user.id)
      end
    end

    def reply?
      self.content.match( USERNAME_REGEX )
    end

    def people_replied
      users = []
      self.content.clone.gsub!( USERNAME_REGEX ).each do |username|
        user = User.find_by_username(username[1..-1])
        users << user if user
      end
      users.uniq
    end
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                  :username
  has_secure_password

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  VALID_UNAME_REGEX = /^[a-z](\w*[a-z0-9])*$/i

  has_many :micropost, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :replies, :class_name => 'Recipient', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :received_replies, :through => :replies, :source => 'micropost'

  def to_param
    self.username
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution did not involve any has_many: associations or scope. It might be more crude but it seems to work.

This is what I did:

1. Added `user_name` to User
2. Added `in_reply_to` to Micropost
3. Used a regexp in the controller to scan new posts for an @user_name and pick out the correlating user_id
4. Save that user_id in the micropost's `in_reply_to`
5. Add to the feed's SQL query to pick out posts where `in_reply_to` matches the user's id

My repo is here: 
https://github.com/paul-ylz/sample_app

Answer (score 0):

I thought Michael Hartl's hint at "adding an in_reply_to column in the microposts" was over complicating things a bit- all you're doing is scanning micropost content. Take a look at my solution:

User_Controller method to include @content in feed

```
#first of all, if you ever want to paginate an array, you need to include
#'will_paginate/array', otherwise you'll experience problems. 
require 'will_paginate/array'
def show
    current_page = params[:page]
    per_page = params[:per_page]

    #creates an activity feed
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @ears_burning = Array.new     #<<-- this is my @replies array
    Micropost.all.each do |m|
      #this looks for a username drop in the post, for example "greenranger"
      if(m.content.include?(@user.username))
        #the micropost with the username(s) is added to the array
        @ears_burning.push(m)
      end
    end

    #my example app, users can also post blogs called "articles", hence
    #the additional arrays, but it serves as a good example as to how I
    #tackled the problem. As you can see, I merge them all into one array
    @array = @user.microposts + @user.articles + @ears_burning

    #This is the user profile activity array, sorted and paginated by 
    #created_at time. Simple!
    @activity = @array.sort_by(&:created_at).reverse!
    @pagination = @activity.paginate(page: params[:show], :per_page => 5)

    # anything else that happens in show
end
```

I looks a bit untidy, but it gets the job done. You'll notice that this only looks for the username, not the @, so this will work for just typing someone elses username within a micropost. I kept it like this because social sites like twitter automatically include a user's profile, with or without the '@' sign in front of the name anyway, but this can be changes slightly by using the regex I use in the view code below.

The drawback with this is that if a user has thousands of linked microposts, then you may notice performance issues- but there's ways around that, just like there is with database related performance issues.

To add a nice "twitter" spin on things, I added a link to tagged usernames in the micropost feed on the home page. Again, there's many ways to do this, but I thought the easiest and most effective way to do this would be for the _micropost partial to build each micropost word-by-word, scanning each for a "@" tag. The microposts have a 140 character limit, so it's never going to be a huge job. This code would go wherever you display microposts:

```
<!-- micropost main content -->
<span class = "content">
    <% words = mp.content.split(" ") %>
    <% words.each do |e| %>
        <!-- this is where the magic happens, re-builds micropost -->
        <% if e.include?("@") %>
            <!-- adds a link to the user profile if '@' is detected -->
            <%= link_to e, User.find_by_username(e[/@.*/].split('@')[+1][/[^ ]+/]
                        .delete(",")) %> <!-- that regex I was on about -->
        <% else %>
            <!-- posts the word in sequence if not a tag -->
            <%= e %>
        <% end %>  
        <!-- end of magic -->              
    <% end %>
</span>
```

The downside to this is that it does bring a bit of logic into the view parts of the Rails application- but it's unavoidable in some cases. Hope this helps!